# Ruby on Rails Honeybadger integration does not work - kinda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, tracking

I integrated honeybadger into my ruby on rails application. It all worked very well and also the rake test task works as intended. Afterwards I caused exceptions on purpose in order to 'populate' the dashboard, so that I can evaluate the look and feel and so on. But somehow, no errors or exceptions get tracked. I used the guide to install and integrate honeybadger and as I mentioned earlier the exception raised by the rake task is tracked properly.

```
begin
  raise('This is an error')
rescue => ex
  notify_honeybadger(ex)
end
```

This is an actual code sample from my application. Usually honeybadger has rails middleware hooks, so that I do not need to notify it manually. But even if I do so nothing gets tracked at all. Does anyone have an advice for me?

best regards

Comment: Have you found an answer on your question? Do you try to make and exception on localhost?

Comment: Ah yes thanks. The support was very helpful and I got it running. Unfortunately there were some other issues, which prevented me to use it in my actual project. Thanks for your help anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to test it on the localhost you need to add the following option to honeybadger initializer:

```
config.development_environments = %w(test)
```

This option is the list of environments in which notifications should not be sent and by default `development` env in the list. See detailed explanation of the configuring option [here](http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/133-development-configuration-options).

Answer (score 1):

As of Honeybadger 2.0, initializers are no longer being promoted; in Rails 4 apps, you will likely get warnings

```
[rails console]
UPGRADE WARNING: Honeybadger.configure was removed in v2.0 and has no effect. 
Please upgrade: https://www.honeybadger.io/s/gem-upgrade
```

Instead, Rails will use config/honeybadger.yml

```
[config/honeybadger.yml]
---
api_key: 'xxxxxx'
metrics.enabled: false
development_environments: ["test", "cucumber"]
```

As stated earlier, you will need to make sure `development_environments` does not include "development".

Use `force: true` to make sure that filters are ignored.

```
[rails console]
Honeybadger.notify(Exception.new("asdf"), force: true)
```

If you see something like this

[image: successful Honeybadger request]

then that should be a good indicator that your test was sent.

Verify successful receipt in Honeybadger console.  Filter by the "development" environment if necessary.

[image]

References

1. http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/41-manually-sending-exceptions-and-events
2. http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/198-gem-configuration
3. http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/197-upgrading-to-honeybadger-2-0